# Repeat for different sets of times

Tags: r, repeat

I have a data frame with 25 values, and I'd like to repeat 1:3, each value 10 times (so first 10 values have 1, next 10 have 2, next 5 have 3).

But, since my 3rd set of values is not a full 10, I am getting the error that my replacement has more rows than my data. I'm wondering why length handles this with no problem, but times doesn't.

Is the answer as simple as I think it is?

```
df$y <- rep(1:3, times = 10, length = nrow(df))
```

Comment: `rep(1:3, c(10, 10, 5))`

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Thanks!